# Перенаправлять все обращения на один url

Tags: php, nginx

Вопрос вот какой: каким образом я могу настроить nginx, чтобы он по любому пути после / выполнял один и тот же php-файл?

Например, у меня есть CentOS, PHP 7.3, nginx. В /home/test/ лежит index.php, результат исполнения которого должен отдаваться и по domain.foo/ и по domain.foo/random/path

Текущий конфиг:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name domain.foo;

    root /home/test;
    index index.php ;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|js|ico|xml|wolf2)$ {
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
        expires max;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
location / {
    try_files $uri /index.php$is_args$args;
}
```